# Front End instance hours Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Does my "index.html" also serve as a static resource?

I have an application which does not have any JSP files but just html, js and css files. How can I manage them efficiently in the web.xml or appengine-web.xml so that my FrontEnd instance hours are reduced?.

Answer (score 2):

> Does my "index.html" also serve as a static resource?

It depends if you declare it a static resource or not.

You can declare resources as static via [appengine-web.xml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref) (look for `<public-root>` and `<static-files>`). Static resources are served directly by GAE, without chewing into your app's instance hours quota.

Note: if your app **only serves static** content you *might* find it more convenient to use the `app.yaml` config file instead of appengine-web.xml (as non-Java apps do) - the actual app sandbox doesn't really matter since you don't actually have app code in this case. See [Serving Static Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/serving-static-files) and/or look for `static_dir` and  `static_files` in the [app.yaml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appref).

Comment: How do I switch from using appengine-web.xml to app.yaml? With a bit of research I did find out the app.yaml was easier to do. But for the time being I stuck with, 

<static-files>
        <include path="/index.html"/>
        <include path="/css/**"/>
        <include path="/img/**"/>
        <include path="/js/**"/>
        <include path="/lib/**"/>
        <include path="/templates/**"/>
</static-files>

Is this fine?

Comment: Just remove `appengine-web.xml` and add `app.yaml` to your app (you may need to change the way you deploy the app accordingly). WRT your appengine-web.xml content I'm not sure, I've only used `app.yaml`.

Comment: I'll probably test out this configuration today and tomorrow. If this don't work out, I'll try adding the app.yaml file. I'm using IntelliJ to deploy apps for Google App Engine. Earlier I used to use Eclipse. Should i switch back to eclipse?

Comment: Whichever you feel more comfortable with, as long as it does the job.